# Surefire report shows doubled tests count using testng

Tags: testng, maven-surefire-plugin

When the build runs, it shows 41 test:
[image]

But in the surefire report in Aws the tests count is 82 (each test appears twice):

[image]

I'm using testng 7.3.0, surefire version 3.0.0-M5 (the latest version currently have on maven repository.

Edit:

in target->surefire-reports->junitreports folder I see twice of each class,
once like this: `"TEST-LoginTests.xml"`
and once like this: `"Test-Sanity.LoginTests.xml".`
Sanity is a package.

pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>14</source>
                <target>14</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.327</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>25.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
        <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

buildspec.yml:

```
    version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto11
    commands:
      - apt update
      - curl -O https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14/076bab302c7b4508975440c56f6cc26a/36/GPL/openjdk-14_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
      - tar xvf openjdk-14_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
      - mv jdk-14 /opt/
      - /opt/jdk-14/bin/java --version
  build:
    commands:
      - env JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-14 PATH=/opt/jdk-14/bin:$PATH mvn --version
      - env JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-14 PATH=/opt/jdk-14/bin:$PATH mvn -Dtestng.dtd.http=true surefire-report:report
reports: #New
  SurefireReports: # CodeBuild will create a report group called "SurefireReports".
    files: #Store all of the files
      - '**/*'
    base-directory: 'target/surefire-reports' # Location of the reports
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Pls check it out with multiple versions of the plugin and TestNG library. Additionally, check the count in the XML files which are located in target/surefire-reports.

Comment: It happens on every version of testng library. And about the target folder please see my edit

Comment: The folder "junitreports" is not created by Surefire. I guess it's created by TestNG. The surefire's XML files should appear directly in "target/surefire-reports".
"TEST-LoginTests.xml" is a typical Surefire XML file, but it should contain the package name as well. The second "Test-Sanity.LoginTests" does not end with ".xml". Please create a reproducible project in GitHub.

Comment: can't add the project to github. The Test-Sanity.LoginTests.xml ends with ".xml" as well.

Comment: TestNG also generates reports and i guess it happens in the folder "junitreports".

Comment: Can you post the POM with the surefire plugin? Child POM and parent with the plugin too.

Comment: That's why it shows each test twice? how can I fix it? added POM

Comment: Is it the Allure report? I guess you should configure the Allure to look up the subfolder and not the root.

Comment: yes. Well maybe it is the reason why it is twice.

Comment: it isn't allure report. I run "mvn -Dtestng.dtd.http=true surefire-report:report". maybe both testng and surefire provides xml, added buildspec.yml

Comment: I guess the AWS takes both reports. Simply "mvn clean" and avoid using "surefire-report:report". The TestNG's report might be enough.

Comment: Due to "surefire-report:report" runs the tests and generates the reports, try to only run the tests "mvn test". The TestNG generates the reports along the execution of the tests. So it should be worth to do it this way.